# SalesForce API: OAuth authorization error 1800

Tags: oauth, salesforce, oauth-2.0, force.com

I am brand new to SalesForce development, and want to explore the API and its capabilities. I have created a new Developer Edition account. I have not yet tried to access the API programmatically, but I am trying (unsuccessfully) to access it via both the Workbench ( https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php ) and the Apigee Console ( https://apigee.com/console/salesforce ).

For some reason, in both cases I'm redirected to a URL with **OAuth error code 1800** (e.g. https://na15.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessErrorPage.apexp?oauth_error_code=1800&display=popup in the Workbench case). At this URL, I am getting a screen with the text **"Remote Access Authorization Error" - "There was a problem in setting up your remote access"**. What am I doing wrong?

Some additional details:

- I can log into SalesForce just fine, the problem only occurs with API/OAuth access
- I have not touched anything in my brand-new Developer Edition account, except for (1) populating it with some sample data (Leads, Accounts, Contacts), and (2) resetting the security token (through "My Personal Information" -> "Reset My Security Token")
- On the WorkBenh login screen, it does not matter which API version I choose (tried 24, 25 and 26), and I am using "Production" for the Environment since my login doesn't seem to work at all for Pre-Release or Sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(not a real answer, I expect to update it frequently as the situation develops)

Weird.

Yes, Developer Edition is a "Production" as far as connecting apps are concerned. You might have to file a Case with Salesforce Support (Help&Training link in the upper right corner).

Workbench does use API (and probably so does this Apigee thingie) but if you're using your username & pass I don't see how it might go to OAuth...

Can you download any other SF-related tooling (Data Loader, Force.com IDE, Real Force Explorer, Excel Connector, some iPad/Android app... hell, Chatter for Desktop even) and try the connectivity?

Sometimes API products don't display special field for the security token (which you can bypass by entering longer string in the password field: "passwordSecurityToken") but Workbench never asked for a token when I was accessing my Dev. Edition.

Comment: Connectivity works fine with at least one iPhone app (it asked me for username, password and security token). Tried concatenated passwordSecurityToken at the Workbench login screen, it complained about invalid credentials (same error message as for a wrong password).

Comment: To anyone else who may be in the same boat: Looks like it's a problem with the na15 instance (or all new accounts). Ironically, the same problem prevents me from opening a support case as well. User "eyescream" went above and beyond to help me, replicating the problem with a new account, providing his own SalesForce Dev Edition credentials to unblock my work, and opening a support case.

Comment: Looks like you're not the only one. Link back ;) http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/salesforce-developer-workbench-hosted-version-oauth-error-remote-access-author ...OK, now it's seriously time for me to go 2 bed

Answer (score 2):

There was an issue with OAuth on NA15, but should be resolved now. I tested with Workbench with a brand new NA15 org and its working as expected.

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization

Comment: i <3 workbench, who ever wrote that is the awesomest!! if only i knew who that was ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this when I try and "short circuit" the auth url by decoding the startUrl param and going straight to it in a tab that's already logged in. For example

1. login to some org on `na14.salesforce.com`
2. click sfdx authorize an org in vs code with default url
3. get sent to a url like `https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=%2Fsetup%2Fsecur%2FRemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp%3Fsource%3D<long_base64_encoded_string>`
4. use a url decoder (i.e. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to translate that to `https://login.salesforce.com/?startURL=/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=<long_base64_encoded_string>`
5. change the url to match the domain i'm logged in as, i.e. `https://na14.salesforce.com/?startURL=/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=<long_base64_encoded_string>`
6. go through the standard oauth grant
7. success

For the most part that works fine, but in some cases I get that wonderful oauth error 1800. In those cases I've been able to work around the issue by specifying the specific domain my instance is on when starting the oauth authorization. Using the above example for step 2 I would chose `https://na14.salesforce.com` for the the url (other oauth flows typically provide a similar custom url input, but ymmv). Voila, step 7 is successful.

Can't say for sure if that's exactly what will happen for others.